# Syntax error while requesting report from Uber

Tags: python, authorization, uber-api

I am trying to send a post request to `https://api.uber.com/v1/eats/report`, but I am getting a syntax error. However, when I am sending the same request through Postman it is working fine. Any help would be great, thanks.

Error:

```
curl -F 'client_secret=<CLIENT_SECRET>' \
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Code:

```
import requests
import json

base_url = 'https://api.uber.com/v1/eats/report'


payload = {
        "report_type" : "PAYMENT_DETAILS_REPORT",
        "store_uuids" : ["storeuuid-storeuuid-storeuuid"],
        "start_date" : "2021-01-01",
        "end_date" : "2021-01-10"
        }

r = requests.post(base_url, data=json.dumps(data), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json',"Authorization": "Bearer mytoken")
```

Comment: Close the `dict` in your `request()`

Comment: The above code works fine. There was an issue with the token.

Comment: The above code does **not** work fine from an SO user perspective. The code cannot be used in its current form, as we have to define the variables which have been left out, and close the `dict` in the `requests.post()` as it causes a syntax error. This is why i mentioned the missing `}`